# Splitting a string into an array

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I'm having trouble splitting this string into an array in the pattern I need it to be. The string is:

```
ATTRIBUTE1: +VALUE1;
ATTRIBUTE2: -VALUE2%;
```

I essentially need an array like this:

```
array (
    [0] => "ATTRIBUTE1", 
    [1] => "+", 
    [2] => "VALUE1", 
    [3] => "%"
)
array (
    [0] => "ATTRIBUTE2", ...
)
```

The "%" is optional, but the +/- sign is not. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
$text= "ATTRIBUTE1: +VALUE1;\nATTRIBUTE2: -VALUE2%;";
echo "STRING\n" . $text . "\n\n";

preg_match_all("~
                ^             # match start of line
                ([^:]+):\s*   # match anything that's not a ':' (attribute), followed by a colon and spaces
                ([+-])        # match a plus or a minus sign
                ([^%;]+)      # match anything that's not a '%' or ';' (value)
                (%?)          # optionally match percent sign 
                ;\s*$         # match ';' then optional spaces and end of line
                ~mx", $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
```

Prints:

```
STRING
ATTRIBUTE1: +VALUE1;
ATTRIBUTE2: -VALUE2%;

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ATTRIBUTE1: +VALUE1;
            [1] => ATTRIBUTE1
            [2] => +
            [3] => VALUE1
            [4] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ATTRIBUTE2: -VALUE2%;
            [1] => ATTRIBUTE2
            [2] => -
            [3] => VALUE2
            [4] => %
        )

)
```

You might have to play around with the regex, but it's got comments now so it shouldn't be too hard to figure it out.

Comment: Heh I appreciated the explanation to the regex, I've always had trouble with that. This is what I need. +1

Comment: @Alper I got the "% is optional, but the +/- sign is not." backwards. I fixed the regex to reflect the change.

Comment: I just tested it on my code and I saw that. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: @Alper BTW I had to fix it twice, and only the version posted now works correctly. Don't know if you got this one or my previous fix.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you could do:

```
$str=explode(": ",$str);
$array[0]=$str[0];
$array[1]=substr($str[1],0,1);
if(substr($str[1],strlen($str[1])-1)=="%"){
    $array[2]=substr($str[1],1,strlen($str[1])-2);
    $array[3]="%";
}else
    $array[2]=substr($str[1],1);
```

Comment: You may have to play around with it a bit, but this will get the basic idea across hopefully.

Comment: Especially since the OP is using keywords that seem like they will change in length, this would need to be totally rewritten for each different variant of it, which, if he has hundreds or thousands of groups like that, is not feasible.